# Open Stack Volume won't attach

Tags: openstack, volumes

I am using openstack to create a Centos7 VM.

I can get the VM to run but the installer hits a snag at the first page.

It needs a Disk to install to (Installation Destination)
   I thought this was the volume that I attached using the openstack app. I used the volume's edit attachments and it pops up saying it will attach it; the volume is never listed as attached to ANY instance I attach it to.

It also needs an Installation Source, which I was using the URL from the mirror site I used. Here is the URL:
[ISO URL](http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/)

I used the net Install ISO. I tried the same url for the installation source and I also tried the URL but change isos to os or this:

[OS URL](http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create VMs in Openstack you are not supposed to go through the installation process. In the cloud you use cloud images that are ready to boot.

You should use a Centos cloud image.

Try to load this Centos7 image into your openstack glance:
http://ubuntu.mirror.cloud.switch.ch/engines/images/2016-04-15/centos7.raw

You should be able to boot your VM and boot with the username centos and the public key you provide with cloud-init.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the RAW image. I was wondering how to provied the public key to the login? I have found and tried to used that image before with no luck. I am on a windows system and using the dashboard. I have never used the console before. Any more tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the image I linked has cloud-init preinstalled. At boot cloud init will ask to the openstack metadata server the public key for ssh access. First create a openstack keypair. Then when you boot the vm specify in horizon or in the command line what keypair to use